# Reduce image size upto max 100 kb and with fix dimension 512x512 in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to create sticker image from image captured from default camera.

I need to resize this image with specific 512x512 size and with maximum size of 100 kb. but, i am not able to find any solution.

I have tried to resize image for 512x512. with below code.

```
var image = imgFront?.resizeWithWidth(width: 512)

extension UIImage {

    func resizeWithWidth(width: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: width, height: width)))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = self

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: width, height: width), false, scale)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        imageView.layer.render(in: context)
        guard let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return nil }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return result
    }
}
```

this makes image in 512x512 properly. but, when i try to reduce size of image below 100 kb with below method, it changes the dimension of image.

```
extension UIImage {

    func resized(withPercentage percentage: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        let canvasSize = CGSize(width: 512, height: 512)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(canvasSize, false, scale)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: canvasSize))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }

    func resizedTo100KB() -> UIImage? {
        guard self.pngData() != nil else { return nil }
        let megaByte = 800.0

        var resizingImage = self
        var imageSizeKB = 990.0 // ! Or devide for 1024 if you need KB but not kB

        while imageSizeKB > megaByte { // ! Or use 1024 if you need KB but not kB
            guard let resizedImage = resizingImage.resized(withPercentage: 0.1),
                let imageData = resizedImage.pngData() else { return nil }

            resizingImage = resizedImage
            imageSizeKB = Double(imageData.count) / megaByte // ! Or devide for 1024 if you need KB but not kB
        }

        return resizingImage
    }
}
```

can any one suggest me good solution to achieve this?

**Constraints**

- Image dimension must be 512x512
- Image size must be any size below 100
  kb.

Answer (score 0):

You should use jpg data instead of png data to get image have small byte size.

Comment: I have tried with jpgdata. it still returns image of bigger than required size. Is it possible for you to share any other code sample?

Comment: What is compress quality with jpg data?

Comment: I just try with 0.1. Result of 500x500 jpg is about 20kb

Comment: yes, some image can work. but, when i try clicking image from rear camera. which will be high resolution. this code does not work and produce around 300 kb sized images.

Comment: @DhavalBhimani please use 0.0 compress quantily for minimum size. But quantily of image is lowest. I think 0.0 will work for all case of you

Comment: i have tried 0.0 also, still image size is 400 kb. do you code sample, which i can try?
self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.0)

Comment: Unbelivable. Can you upload your sample project. I just download image from internet and resize. You used image picker?

Comment: Here is the sample project . https://www.dropbox.com/s/1d1x0fwc53xqutr/Test.zip?dl=0

Comment: @DhavalBhimani I just used your sample and take a picture. imageSizeKB has value is 14.3. It work, no problem. `imageData` has only `11507` byte

Comment: I think you confuse something. I test 5 times, maximum of output is 20kb

Comment: when i click with camera. image size is still more than 100 kb. not sure where is the problem.

Comment: @DhavalBhimani I used with camera of iPhone X. It always bellow 100kb